# Where should package authors place benchmarks?

Tags: r, package, benchmarking, devtools

There is [lots](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=benchmarks+in+R+packages) of info about benchmarking in R. Further more there is lots about unit tests, primarily using the handy **testthat** package. But where should package authors place their benchmarks?

Options I have seen:

- In the demo folder, e.g.: https://github.com/edzer/sfr/blob/6f2d6a64d6caf4eb159d9f808c0b16a47759fab5/demo/bm_wkb.R
- In the Wiki, e.g.: https://github.com/osmdatar/osmdata/wiki/sf-comparisons
- In the README.Rmd
- In the test folder, but to run only locally (not sure how to extract and document the results this way though)

Each have pros and cons, none seem ideal.

Which is best of those?

Is there a better way than the above?

Context: I'm asking this in the context of a need, to test potential improvements in performance in our stplanr package: https://github.com/ropensci/stplanr/issues/155